# find users on twitter and save them as a list

Tags: python, list, search, twitter

I am a beginner in python, here is what I did and want to do with python: I searched for a hashtag in tweeter and saved the users that used the hashtag, now my question is how I can save these users as a list, since I want to find followings of these users later.
Here is my code:

```
for i in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#hashtag").items():
    author = i.author.id
    tweet = i.text.replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ').replace('\r\n',' ')
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: for i in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#hashtag").items():
    author = i.author.id
    tweet = i.text.replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ').replace('\r\n',' ')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can use a set https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set. You can use something like this:

```
hashtag_search_results = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#hashtag")
authors = set()

for i in hashtag_search_results.items():
    author = i.author.id
    tweet = i.text.replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ').replace('\r\n',' ')

    authors.add(author)
    if len(authors) == 100:
        break

# work with the authors set
```

Comment: it is just I am afraid it gives me list of 100 authors but there can be repeated ids, while I want 100 different authors.

Comment: They can not be reapeted. It's a ```set```! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting:

```
hashtag_search_results = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#hashtag")
authors = []
for i in hashtag_search_results.items():
    author = i.author.id
    tweet = i.text.replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ').replace('\r\n',' ')

    authors.append(author)

# work with the authors list
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful comment. Now I want to limit the list of authors to 100. I do not need this loop to find all the auther I need it to stop after it get 100 authors, however, this also means that authors should not be repeated in the list, so at the end I want to have  a list of 100 different ids.

Comment: See comment below